# Need to speed up my UPDATE QUERY based on the EXPLAIN PLAN

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I am updating my table data using a temporary table and it takes forever and it still has not completed. So I collected an explain plan on the query. Can someone advise me on how to tune the query or build indexes on them.

**The query:**

```
UPDATE w_product_d A
SET A.CREATED_ON_DT = (SELECT min(B.creation_date)
                       FROM mtl_system_items_b_temp B
                       WHERE  to_char(B.inventory_item_id) = A.integration_id
                       and B.organization_id IN ('102'))
where A.CREATED_ON_DT is null;
```

**Explain plan:**

```
Plan hash value: 1520882583

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name                    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT    |                         | 47998 |   984K|    33M  (2)|110:06:25 |
|   1 |  UPDATE             | W_PRODUCT_D             |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL | W_PRODUCT_D             | 47998 |   984K|  9454   (1)| 00:01:54 |
|   3 |   SORT AGGREGATE    |                         |     1 |    35 |            |          |
|*  4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B_TEMP |  1568 | 54880 |   688   (2)| 00:00:09 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("A"."CREATED_ON_DT" IS NULL)
   4 - filter("B"."ORGANIZATION_ID"=102 AND TO_CHAR("B"."INVENTORY_ITEM_ID")=:B1)

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

Comment: If I were you, I'd consider adding an index on w_product_d of (integration_id, created_on_dt). And perhaps a function-based index on mtl_system_items_b_temp of (to_char(inventory_item_id))

Comment: I have seen this kind of updates to be a lot faster if they were changed to an corresponding `MERGE` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a `MERGE` statement.  It will likely go faster because it can read all the `mtl_system_items_b_temp` records at once rather than reading them over-and-over again for each row in `w_product_d`.

Also, your tables look like they're part of an Oracle e-BS environment.  In the `MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B` in such an environment, the `INVENTORY_ITEM_ID` and `ORGANIZATION_ID` columns are `NUMBER`.  You seem to be using `VARCHAR2` in your tables.  Whenever you don't use the correct data types in your queries, you invite performance problems because Oracle must implicitly convert to the correct data type and, in doing so, loses its ability to use indexes on the column.  So, make sure your queries treat each column correctly according to it's datatype.  (E.g., if a column is a `NUMBER` use `COLUMN_X = 123` instead of `COLUMN_X = '123'`.

Here's the `MERGE` example:

```
MERGE INTO w_product_d t
USING ( SELECT to_char(inventory_item_id) inventory_item_id_char, min(creation_date) min_creation_date
        FROM   mtl_system_items_b_temp 
        WHERE  organization_id IN ('102')  -- change this to IN (102) if organization_id is a NUMBER field!
      ) u
ON ( t.integration_id = u.inventory_item_id_char AND t.created_on_dt IS NULL )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.created_on_dt = nvl(t.created_on_date, u.min_creation_date)  -- NVL is just in case...
```

Comment: Thanks McPeak. I will follow this!

Comment: Only if there are sufficient constraints defined for Oracle to be sure that `w_product_d` is key-preserved in that implicit view.

Answer (score 2):

For this query:

```
UPDATE w_product_d A
    SET A.CREATED_ON_DT = (SELECT min(B.creation_date)
                           FROM mtl_system_items_b_temp B
                           WHERE to_char(B.inventory_item_id) = A.integration_id
                                 and B.organization_id IN ('102'))
    where A.CREATED_ON_DT is null;
```

You have a problem.  Why are you creating a temporary table with the wrong type for `inventory_item_id`?  That is likely to slow down any access.  So, let's fix the table first and then do the update:

```
alter table mtl_system_items_b_temp
    add better_inventory_item_id varchar2(255);  -- or whatever the right type is

update mtl_system_items_b_temp
    set better_inventory_item_id = to_char(inventory_item_id);
```

Next, let's define the appropriate index:

```
create index idx_mtl_system_items_b_temp_3 on mtl_system_items_b_temp(better_inventory_item_id, organization_id, creation_date);
```

Finally, an index on `w_product_d` can also help:

```
create index idx_ w_product_d_1 w_product_d(CREATED_ON_DT);
```

Then, write the query as:

```
UPDATE w_product_d p
    SET CREATED_ON_DT = (SELECT min(t.creation_date)
                         FROM mtl_system_items_b_temp t
                         WHERE t.better_nventory_item_id) = p.integration_id and
                               t.organization_id IN ('102')
                        )
    WHERE p.CREATED_ON_DT is null;
```

Comment: Wouldn't the index just on created_on_dt be ignored, since you're checking for `created_on_dt is null`, and nulls will never be stored in that index? That's why I suggested an index on (integration_id, created_on_dt), anyway.

Comment: Excellent! I missed to_char conversion. I never knew that would cause the overhead. I am adding the updated explain and the query. Do you think the update query can be improved because it is still projected at 40 minutes.:

Comment: @Boneist Do you want me to create an index on all these three:
better_inventory_item_id, organization_id, creation_date on TEMP table?
 and IGNORE index on CREATED_ON_DT?

Comment: Go ahead with the index on the temp table, but regarding the index on the w_product_d table, I'd make sure that you included a second column in the index, along with created_on_dt. If you don't, then your null created_on_dts won't be stored in the index (since if all columns in an ordinary btree index are null, the row isn't stored in the index). Depending on what other queries use the w_product_d table, it might make sense to create an index on (integration_id, created_on_dt) or you might see improvements for this query if the index was on (created_on_dt, integration_id) instead

Comment: @Boneist The explain plan for the update process after creating the index on w_product_d table with the combination  (created_on_dt, integration_id)  is 00:38:00. Is this the best I can achieve or is there anything else than can be done? It is really a great improvement from 110:06:25 to 00:38:28!!!

Comment: @Dilip Have you tried running the query? Also, what is the execution plan now? It would be good if you could updated your question to include the latest plan you have. Also, have you gathered stats recently on the tables? Also, is MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B_TEMP an ordinary table or is it a GTT?

Comment: Actually the query ran in 3 seconds. It updated 50,000 rows. Thank you all!

Comment: @Boneist It was a GTT. Would that be changing anything?

Comment: @Dilip A GTT changes the stats gathering decision- ie. It's generally better to leave GTTs without stats and let dynamic sampling do its thing.

Comment: @Dilip . . . 3 seconds is pretty good for something that started off at 2 hours.  How fast is the merge?